# Allowing all ports from an IP

Tags: iptables, linux-networking

I have successfully entered the following command to iptables

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 5000:5020 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow Ports 5000s"
```

However, AFAIK this allows access to those ports on any NIC. How do I ammend the above command to only allow from say 10.0.0.1 to 10.0.0.127?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow from only certain IP or range use the `-s` flag and an ip and netmask
for example

sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp **-s 10.0.0.0/25** --dport 5000:5020 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow Ports 5000s"

Will allow only from systems with an IP of 10.0.0.1 thru 10.0.0.126

There is more information here [IP Tables How TO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo)

To help you find a subnet to use to get all the needed IP's you can use a subnet calculator like the one here [Subnet Calculator](http://www.subnet-calculator.com/subnet.php?net_class=A)